# PHP Concatenation and Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, concatenation, advanced-custom-fields, string-concatenation

I am using wordpress with  Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) and trying to concatenate `the_title();` together with a PHP variable `$address_city`and then place both of them in between some HTML. (I have a hierarchical taxonomy of 'citystates' whereI put in the city, state and zip code).

My full code is as follows:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'citystates' );
$address_city = (' '. $terms[1]->name . ', '. $terms[2]->name . ' '. $ 
terms[0]->name); 
$address_beg = the_title();
$address_full = ($address_city ." ". $address_beg);
echo "<p>" .$address_full. "</p>";`
```

If my title is "1234 56th Street" and the taxonomy of citystates (`$address_city`) is "New York, New York 11001" Then it should be shown "1234 56th Street New York, New York 11001" while being wrapped in a "p" tag.

My issue is that only the "New York, New York 11001" is being wrapped in "p" tag but not the full address. 
The HTML output I get is:

```
"
1234 56th Street    "
<p> New York, New York 11001  
</p>
```

I know this is simple stuff but I need help figuring it out and have already spent a lot of time googling an answer. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: use get_the_title() in place of the_title()

Comment: @Jaydp It worked! Thank you so much! Wow, just 3 letters and an underscore makes such a difference

Comment: Read about the [WordPress template tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags). The docs will explain the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in a comment to the questions and is rather very simple.

use `get_the_title()` in place of `the_title()`